# JS: Illegal return statement when closing iterator with for of loop

Tags: javascript, iterator

I'm trying to break iterator early and return the result but got `Illegal return statement` error.

```
const gen = function *(){
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}
for (let i of gen()) {
  console.log(i)
  return i
}
```

From MDN [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

> In for...of loops, abrupt iteration termination can be caused by break, throw or return. In these cases, the iterator is closed.

While break and throw works as expected.

Comment: This code doesn't produce any error for me, unless I run it directly in a browser console. I presume you've placed the code in some function, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return statement isn't inside a function.  This works:

```
const gen = function *(){
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

function doLoop() {
  for (let i of gen()) {
    console.log(i)
    return i
  }
}

doLoop()
```

You'd get the same error if you just typed `return`.  It's about where return is executed and doesn't have anything to do with generators.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` is outside of the generator function. You don't break generators outside of them, as there's very little reason to do so.

Comment: My use case is the generator is from a third party library where I don't have control when to break.

Comment: And can you state why I cannot return outside of generator function? because break works as expected.

Comment: Because that `break` works inside a loop, it doesn't have anything to do with the generator. I think the best you can do is to read [how generators work](https://codeburst.io/understanding-generators-in-es6-javascript-with-examples-6728834016d5). The idea behing them is really simple.

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem in my case is not how generator work but how for loop work.